# RAILS 6.1 supports multiple has_one_attached in ACTIVE STORAGE?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-on-rails-6.1

There is an [article](https://blog.saeloun.com/2020/02/03/rails-allows-configure-service-for-attachments-to-activestorage.html) describing that RAILS 6.1 will support multiple storage services in one model definition.

I was happy to update to RAILS 6.1 and tried it out.

My Model :

```
...
has_one_attached :accom_paper, service: :upload_accom_paper
has_one_attached :extra_paper, service: :upload_extra_paper
...
```

My storage.yml :

```
upload_accom_paper:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("uploads/accom_paper") %>

upload_extra_paper:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("uploads/extra_paper") %>
```

But when I try to run this code, I get :

`ArgumentError (Cannot configure service :upload_extra_paper for OrderNow#extra_paper):`

So it seems to be the second statement of `has_one_attached` will NOT be supported.

Comment: It seems to be working on a new fresh project. Did you make sure to follow this point `If our project is already using Active Storage and when we upgrade to Rails 6.1, we should run rake app:update to make sure service_name column is added to the internal ActiveStorageBlob model.` ?

Comment: Hi Daniel, 
yes sure - I did run the rails app:update and the rails db:migrate. 
And when I have just one has_one_attached entry in the model file, it works like designed !